# Function in R, passing in variables

Tags: r, function

I am looking to run multiple ANOVAs in R, so I was hoping to write a function.

```
df = iris

run_anova <- function(var1,var2,df) {
  fit = aov(var1 ~ var1 , df)
  return(fit)
}
```

In the iris dataset, the column names are "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"

Assuming that I want to use these columns in the equations, how do I pass them into the run_anova function?  I have tried passing them in as strings

```
run_anova("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", df)
```

that doesn't work because this error appears:
"In storage.mode(v) <- "double" :"

```
run_anova(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, df)
```

When I just pass them in without the quotes, "not found".  How can I pass these names of the df columns into the function?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Would try building a formula from the variable name strings: `fit = aov(as.formula(paste(var1, "~", var2)) , df)`

Comment: or `reformulate(var2, var1)` for short

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Use reformulate to create the formula.  The `do.call` is needed to cause the Call: line in the output to appear nicely but if you don't care about that you can use the shorter version shown in (3).

```
run_anova <- function(var1, var2, df) {
  fo <- reformulate(var2, var1)
  do.call("aov", list(fo, substitute(df)))
}

run_anova("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", iris)
```

giving

```
Call:
   aov(formula = Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data = iris)    

Terms:
                Petal.Length Residuals
Sum of Squares      5.196047 23.110887
Deg. of Freedom            1       148

Residual standard error: 0.3951641
Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```

**2)** Although the use of `eval` is discouraged, an alternative which also gives nice output is:

```
run_anova2 <- function(var1, var2, df) {
  fo <- reformulate(var2, var1)
  eval.parent(substitute(aov(fo, df)))
}

run_anova2("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", iris)
```

**3)** If you don't care about the Call line in the output being nice then this simpler code can be used:

```
run_anova3 <- function(var1, var2, df) {
  fo <- reformulate(var2, var1)
  aov(fo, df)
}

run_anova3("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", iris)
```

giving:

```
Call:
   aov(formula = fo, data = df)
...etc...
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you so much for taking the time to respond

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use `rlang`'s quasi-quotation syntax

```
df = iris

library(rlang)
run_anova <- function(var1, var2, df) {
    var1 <- parse_expr(quo_name(enquo(var1)))
    var2 <- parse_expr(quo_name(enquo(var2)))
    eval_tidy(expr(aov(!!var1 ~ !!var2, data = df)))
}
```

This allows you to do use both strings and unquoted expressions for `var1` and `var2`:

```
run_anova("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", df)
run_anova(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, df)
```

Both expressions return the same result.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck True; but results are the same. The advantage here is that we can use quoted and unquoted expressions.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Yes I understood your comment. It shows `data = df` in the call element of the return `list` but it *does* return the correct `aov` with whatever `data.frame` you gave for the `df` argument of `run_anova`. The only difference between the answers is that the `call` element is different. Results are the same.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck PS. To make things consistent with your results, I have swapped `var1` and `var2`; I had originally `var2 ~ var1`, you have `var1 ~ var2` (OP unfortunately had a typo with `var1 ~ var1`).

Comment: @G.Grothendieck That's not really what OP was asking though. OP tried passing columns names as strings and as unquoted expressions. My answer allows him to do both (or rather: either).